# Question regarding factory overriding in SV UVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a base class `base_class` as follows.

```
class base_class extends uvm_object;
  ...
  ...

  rand int a;

  constraint a_c {a inside {[0:100]};}
endclass
```

There is an ext_class as follows

```
class ext_class extends base_class;
  constraint a_c {a inside {[100:150]};}
endclass
```

There is a third class `child_class` that extends from `base_class` as follows

```
class child_class extends base_class;
endclass
```

How can I factory override `base_class` with `ext_class` such that even `child_class` will get the constraint written in `ext_class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the classes as you have requested. `ext_class` and `child_class` are siblings in the inheritance hierarchy. SystemVerilog has only single lines of inheritance. You would have to extend `ext_class` from `child_class` or *vice-versa*.

Another way to approach this is putting your classes variables in class containers that can be overriden independently.

```
class a_container extends uvm_object;
  rand int a;
  constraint a_c {a inside {[0:100]};}
endclass
class a_ext extends a_container;
  constraint a_c {a inside {[100:150]};}
endclass
class base_class extends uvm_object;
  rand a_container a_h = a_container::type_id::create("a_h");
  // ...
endclass
class child_class extends base_class;
  // ...
endclass
```

Now you can independently override `base_class` and `a_container`. You do not need to create a container for every random variable, you can group them together depending on how you want to pattern the overrides.